# Jasmine unit test: ngModelChange calls function or not

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing

I am running unit test for angular app, upon ngModelChange if a function is being because I am testing some logic that is happening inside this function. But my test fails to spy if this function called or not!!!

** component.spec.js**

```
it('should auto compute something', ()=>{
 component.record = "123";
 let spyOnDaemonChange = spyOn(component,'func1').and.callThrough();
 fixture.detectChanges();
 let daemonDOM = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#domelement'));
 daemonDOM.nativeElement.value ="123";
 fixture.detectChanges();
 expect(spyOnDaemonChange).toHaveBeenCalled(); //fails
})
```

**component.ts**

```
func1(){
 if(this.record == "abc"){
   this.num = 88;
 } else {
    this.num = 78; 
   }
}

**component.html**
 <td>
   <input style="width:300px;" id="domelement" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="record" (ngModelChange) ="func1" name="record" required>
 </td>
```

component.record="123" or  daemonDOM.nativeElement.value ="123"; are the same. This must have triggered ngModelChange and called the function, am I correct?

I want the test to detect ngModelChange and call the function

Comment: You should call the function in the event handler: `(ngModelChange)="func1()"`.

Comment: Thanks ConnorsFan

Answer (score 1):

I am able to trigger the change using DOMelement.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));